# YouTube Analytics API Questions

Tags: youtube-api

I'm new to the YouTube Analytics API, and had a couple of questions:

- In order to retrieve Analytics reports, I have to specify the channel ID for the "ids" parameter.  How do I find the channel ID for the OAuth-authenticated user?  I saw in the Sample Application that I can call Channels.list method in the Data API (V3) and use the "mine=true" parameter.  Is this guaranteed to return a single channel?  If not, how do I know which channel is the right one?  What's the recommended way of finding a user's channel ID?
- Once I have the channel ID, I can begin querying for Analytics data. I'd like to query the "views" metric for the channel for the entire history of that channel.  The question is, how do I know how far back to query?  Is there a channel start date?  The Channels.list method mentioned above doesn't return the snippet.publishedAt date for my channel so that doesn't seem to be a reliable way.  How else do I know when to stop?  I guess I could query back until 2005 or so when YouTube was founded but that seems like a bad approach.  Any suggestions?
- The Analytics API supports reports for channels as well as content owners.  Once a user authenticates via OAuth, how do I know if that account is a regular YouTube account vs a CMS content owner account?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The recommended approach is to do a `channels.list(mine=true)`. The first result returned will be the channel corresponding to the currently authorized user. (`channels.list()` returns a list of channels because there are other combinations of request parameters that could result in more than one channel being returned.)
- Going back to some arbitrary date in the past should be harmless. 2005, 2000, etc. The YouTube Analytics backend should know how to properly deal with that, and you'll obviously only get stats that date back to the first views associated with your channel.
- The value of the `ids=` parameter tells the API whether you want to do a report against a channel associated with the current authorized user (`ids=channel==UC...`) or against channels/videos that you have access to as a CMS content owner (`ids=contentOwner==CONTENT_OWNER_NAME`).

Comment: Thanks Jeff for the prompt response. I'm still confused about the 3rd question. I'm building an app that will ask a user to authenticate via OAuth.  After authenticating, how do I know if this user is a regular user (so that I would make channel report queries) or if the user is a CMS content owner so that I should make content owner queries.  If CMS, how do I get their CONTENT_OWNER_NAME?

Comment: You'd need to code explicitly for those two different scenarios. If you think that there's a chance that some CMS content owners are going to use your app, you're going to have to build a different UI flow in which you ask them to enter their content owner name before running reports. It might be best to forget about that use case unless you specifically know some of your users will be CMS content owners, though.

Comment: I see.  So I guess there's no way to programmatically determine if a YouTube account is normal vs CMS?  I assume CMS content owners will know their content owner name?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @JerryHardaway Did you ever find out how to do this? I am stuck on the same issue, but there is a lack of support with the youtube api. Some people think it's dead :/

Comment: @EliteGamer - No, I ended up only supporting the normal scenario.

Comment: @jeff Is there any possibility to get past date subscriber/views for any channel(any channel mean:It may be the possibility that the user authorizing the request may not be the owner of the channel).
I got stuck in this.Please help me out!