# How to avoid a cmsUserAccountNotFound in the YouTube V3 API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have login credentials that allow me to manage several youtube channels. There's also a Content Owner account that controls those channels via YT's CMS.

I am trying to upload a video to a specific channel. From my understanding, this requires the OnBehalfOfContentOwner and OnBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel flags. I got the content owner ID from the URL's 'o' parameter (as in https://www.youtube.com/my_channels?o=[id]), and the channel ID through similar means. However, when I call the API using this OnBehalfOfContentOwner ID, I get a cmsUserAccountNotFound back. This also happens when I use the Channels:list API on the YT docs website with the same OnBehalfOfContentOwner ID.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Which credentials should I make sure my user has in order to prevent this?

I found a workaround this where I create separate request tokens for each channel, but I'd like to be able to dynamically select the upload channel.

Answer (score 1):

This is the error you're getting based on [Youtube Core API errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#youtube.api.CommonRequestError):

> forbidden (403) cmsUserAccountNotFound  The CMS user is not allowed to
>   act on behalf of the specified content owner.

Things I suggest you to try:

1. Under [Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list), make sure:

> "the CMS account that the user authenticates with must be linked to
>   the specified YouTube content owner."

Full statement [here](https://www.hitchhq.com/youtube/activities/57dfb6607ab5cb2d63b136db):

> "the CMS account  must be linked to the content owner that the
>   onBehalfOfContentOwner parameter specifies. The parameter indicates
>   that the request's authorization credentials identify a YouTube CMS
>   user who is acting on behalf of the content owner specified in the
>   parameter value.
>
> The CMS account that the user authenticates with must
>   be linked to the specified YouTube content owner. This parameter is
>   intended for content partners that own and manage many different
>   YouTube channels. The parameter enables those partners to authenticate
>   once and get access to all of their video and channel data, without
>   having to provide authentication credentials for each individual
>   channel. Specifically in regard to this release, the parameter now
>   enables a content partner to insert, update, or delete videos in any
>   of the YouTube channels that the partner owns."

2. Check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927864/youtube-analytics-api-questions) for additional insight.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message as I was trying to do this using a service account credential file for server to server api calls (in python):

```py
# maybe there are too much scopes ^^'
SCOPES = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-content-owner-readonly",
]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "/path/to/my-service-account-credentials.json"
MY_CONTENT_OWNER_ID = "EwR3********Ms5A"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES
)
youtube_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    "youtube", "v3", credentials=credentials
)
request = youtube_service.channels().list(
    part="id,contentDetails,status,statistics",
    managedByMe="True",
    onBehalfOfContentOwner=MY_CONTENT_OWNER_ID,
)
```

I finaly solved it manually going to https://studio.youtube.com/

Then for each of my accounts > parameters > authorizations > and invite my service account email (as administrator just to be sure).

Then I could access to the data and no longer have this "CMS user is not allowed to act on behalf of the specified content owner" error.